# Humidity is driving me nuts

Tags: dehumidifier

We live in PR. The humidity in my home reaches 80% on most days even when the temperature is 65 outside.Why is this?

Comment: Is this significantly higher than the humidity outside, or causing a problem in some way? Are you trying to also figure out how to lower the humidity?

Comment: Welcome to the tropics?  I really don't know what to say about this...

Comment: What do you mean by "why"? Why is the humidity driving you nuts? Why do you live in Puerto Rico? Why are you plural?

Comment: Around here we often have 68-70 degree dew points in the summer. That means that when the air temperature reaches that number, humidity is 100%. It's not a stretch to imagine relative humidity creeping up inside the home, too. I recommend some reading on basic weather theory.

Answer (score 2):

Relative humidity is the amount of water air can hold at a given temperature and is expressed as a % of the total moisture it can hold at that given temperature. As air temperature rises the amount of water the air can hold increases. As the air temperature  decreases that same amount of air can hold less water. The % of humidity in your home and where you live can rise to 100% at any given temperature. So the 80% humidity only means that the air is saturated to 80% of total capacity.

Comment: What horrible comments: I knew exactly what  they were asking. It was just a question about % of relative humidity, and how it can be higher than the ambient temperature, a mis understanding of how hunidity works.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about the weather, then, boy, I don't know man.  Sounds like you live in a pretty humid area.  Also - outside temp will not necessarily correlate to the internal humidity.

If your question is asking about how to resolve this, then I would heartily recommend a dehumidifier.  I purchased one as the humidity gets pretty high in my house when the heating is on during the winter.  The tech has come on leaps and bounds in the last 20 years, and the little unit I bought for £130 will bring the whole house down to around 40% within a couple hours.